# In production mode in rails, my worker does not see anything in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been struggling all day to figure out why my workers aren't working in Production mode, but they're working in Development mode. Here's what I figured out.

1. In development AND production mode, I can use the `rails c` command to see what's in the database, and it's accurate.
2. However, if I place a `binding.pry` to pause my worker during runtime, it does not see *any* items in the Model. It doesn't make any sense whatsoever. In fact, I can do `Campaign.all` and it shows nothing in there, and then go right back to the rails console and do `Campaign.all` and it shows.

Any ideas?

Here's the output of both the rails console and the `binding.pry` pause, respectively:

```
$ rails c
2.5.1 :009 > SidekiqTask.first
  SidekiqTask Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `sidekiq_tasks`.* FROM `sidekiq_tasks` ORDER BY `sidekiq_tasks`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<SidekiqTask id: 5, campaign_id: 1, job_id: "c19d37f4c70060d3b59059b0", task: "Start Campaign", created_at: "2018-10-04 20:11:03", updated_at: "2018-10-04 20:11:03">
```

and then here's the other one

```
[4] pry(#<CampaignWorker>)> SidekiqTask.first
=> nil
```

Any idea what could possibly be going on here? This issue with it not seeing anything in the model only occurs during the time that the worker runs. It sees it just fine if I look for it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out it was because my Sidekiq instance was not running in production mode. I fixed this by running the following command:

`bundle exec sidekiq --environment production`